Repeated numbering 1 and 2 only
I want to ask about numbering that repeats itself with the same conditions based on Column B and is limited to only 1 and 2 then returns to 1 so on.
as an example :



Column A
Column B




1
John


1
John


1
John


2
Alpha


2
Alpha


1
Thomas


1
Thomas


1
Thomas


2
Charlie


2
Charlie


1
Tony


2
Thomas


1
Delta




"I want to ask..." - OK, go ahead and ask. There's no question here.

You can use
=SCAN(,B2:INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(,0/LEN(B2:B))),LAMBDA(a,c,MOD(a+(c<>OFFSET(c,-1,))-1,2)+1)) 


Same formula with the range provided as a LET variable:
=LET(rng,B2:B,SCAN(,SINGLE(rng):INDEX(rng,MATCH(,0/LEN(rng))),LAMBDA(a,c,MOD(a+(c<>OFFSET(c,-1,))-1,2)+1)))


This is what I'm looking for, very helpful. Thank You
